# All the commit history from SVN is not migrated to GIT

Tags: git, github, svn, version-control

I am a developer and for the first time , I am migrating my whole SVN repository to a GIT repository. As a POC, I have migrated current development branch. Migration was successful with the history as well.
Problem : SVN commit history in GIT
Result of migration : All the history of current dev branch from SVN is migrated , but from the date this branch was created in SVN.
My Expectation : History of every individual file along with its complete history and related code changes.

Ex : My root repository is "MyProject". I have individual code repos for every release, like "MyDevRepo-rel-1.0" etc... I have a file "Helloworld.java" which was created in "MyDevRepo-rel-1.0" which I have been working on since release 1.0 till current release , say it be "MyDevRepo-rel-5.0".
Now, when I migrated "MyDevRepo-rel-5.0" , I have got only current branch commit history for the file HelloWorld.java , but not from release 1.0

Can any one help on this.

Comment: Please may you provide a clear problem statement? I would also like to invite you to learn the differences between SVN and git.

Comment: Does `MyDevRepo-rel-1.0`, `MyDevRepo-rel-5.0` etc are the subfolder under MyProject? If they are subfolder, where does the file `Helloworld.java` located? If the revision release 1.0 already migrated to git repo, all the files in the revision should be viewed correctly unless the file `Helloworld.java` didn't commit into the revision release 1.0. You can double check the svn log to check which revision(s) commit the file `Helloworld.java`.

Comment: 1.MyDevRepo-rel-1.0, MyDevRepo-rel-5.0 etc are the sub folders of MyProject.2.HelloWorld.java was initially created in MyDevRepo-rel1.0. 3.For every release dev cycle, MyDevRepo-rel-1.0 is the first & MydevRepo-rel-5.0 is 5th release.HelloWorld.java has its own commit history right from release 1.0 till 5.0. Let's say HelloWorld.java file has 10 commits for all releases till 5.0 and 5 commits in 5.0. When I migrated 5.0 repo,I got 5 commits history, but my expectation was to get all the 15 commits history (10 till 5.0+5 from rel 5.0). Is my expectation correct,if not please suggest what to do.

Comment: My issue is some thing similar to this : https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/SVN-to-GIT-migration-maintaining-history-when-the-SVN-repo-has/qaq-p/300458

Comment: How did you use git svn command? If you need to migrate all the subfolders and revisions into git repo, the url should like: http://svn-repo/MyProject (not http://svn-repo/MyProject/MydevRepo-rel-5.0).

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks all for responding to my doubts. I am able to resolve this issue and 
the set of commands follow.

My requirement is : MIGRATE EXISTING SVN repository to GIT with all the commit 
history.


md mydirectory
cd mydirectory
git svn init  <SVN_ROOT_URL>
git config --global user.name "MY NAME"
git config --global user.email "MY EMAIL"
git config svn.authorsfile authors.txt
git svn fetch
git svn show-ignore >> .gitignore
git remote -v (to check the remote branches)
git remote add origin <MY_GIT_REPO>.git
git add .
git commit -m "migrating svn to git"
git push -u origin master (this will push your local repo to the git server)
git svn rebase (this command will sync the latest changes from svn to the current git repo)
git push (this command pushes all the latest code checked-out code from SVN to GIT).

Mistake I made : I migrated one individual branch and expected all the 
commit history right from the inception of every file. 

Learnings : If I want all the commit history of every individual file, then 
I had to migrate the entire SVN repository from the root. This resolved my 
problem.
Please add if there are any missing things.
```